# Count subquery in a select - mongoDB

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want to make a query to get a kind of ranking of users with more tweets in my database mongoDB:

```
var TeewtSchema = new Schema({
    userId: Number,
    twweetId : Number,
    createdAt: Date,
    cuerpo: String,
    nameUser: String,
    location: String,
    avatar: String,
    user: String
});
```

MySql that output something similar to:

```
    SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE userId = t.userId ) rank FROM `TABLE 1` t GROUP BY t.userId ORDER BY rank DESC
```

but in mongoDB i have no idea how to do

Comment: Use the Mongo's support for [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as JohnnyHK suggests, you should use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for this.  Something like the following should do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   { $group : { _id : "$userId", numTweets = { $sum : 1 } }, // sum tweets over each user
   { $sort : { numTweets : -1 } } // sort by numTweets in descending order
)
```